# Why mkdir cannot be called in tcl script envoked by git?

Tags: tcl, git

I want to develop custom `git` command using `tcl`. The choice of programming language was done considering ease of learning (as I thought) and availability (`git` ships with `tcl`).

I want to create folder using `tcl` script. Normally I'm calling `mkdir <name>` in the script and it works fine, but in case if it `git` command it is saying: `invalid command name "mkdir"`.

Am I missing some references to be added to my script to make system commands available for me?

The strange thing, that `exec sh` is working. But I don't want to wrap `mkdir` into `sh`... Or is this the only way in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`file mkdir dir ?dir ...?`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M22).

Comment: Magic! Thanks! I didn't imagine that folder manipulation will be grouped with file manipulation in `tcl`... http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M22

Comment: @shytikov While Tcl does do some (deeply gnarly) magic in interactive use to make a direct `mkdir` work, for a script that's disabled (because it can cause surprises with some inputs). The directory creation is in `file` because there's no `directory` command. :-)